# Redefine non-configurable properties using a browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to somehow proxy an object (say `window`) or use `Object.defineProperty` on its existing properties (say `location`) using a browser extension in chrome or firefox? I want to define a few getters and setters to help with code analysis. I could do without setters I suppose (watch expressions exist after all), but I could not find anything that could replace getters. I really do not want to make a custom browser build.

Comment: No, there's no such extension API.